# Agregar condicion a una consulta linq c#

Tags: sql, linq

Tengo esta consulta que me trae registros de un bd

```
var query = from c in db.Checkinout.AsEnumerable()
join u in db.Userinfo on c.Userid equals u.Userid
where c.CheckTime >= buscar1 && c.CheckTime <= buscar2
orderby u.Name ascending, u.Userid
select new
{
    Codigo = c.Userid,
    Cuit = u.UserCode,
    Nombre = u.Name,

    Fecha = c.CheckTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
    Hora = c.CheckTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss"),
    Movimiento = c.CheckType == 0 ? "ENTRADA" : (c.CheckType == 1 ? "SALIDA" : null)
};
```

las variables buscar1 y buscar2 son de 2 datetimepicker el datetimepicker2 es igual al datetimepicker mas 1 dia, lo que que quiero hacer es traer Checktype 0 y 1 del datetimepicker1 y Checktype 1 del datetimepicker2.

Answer (score -1):

No sé si es la mejor manera, pero lo resolví creando una función que devuelve el valor dependiendo de las condiciones:

```
Movimiento = new Func<string>(() =>
        {
            

            if (c.CheckTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") == dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") && c.CheckType == 0)
            {
                return "ENTRADA";
            }
            if (c.CheckTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") == dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") && c.CheckType == 1)
            {
                return "SALIDA";
            }
            if (c.CheckTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") == dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") && c.CheckType == 1)
            {
                return "SALIDA";
            }



            return null;

        }
                              )
             ()
```